# how to calculate the phase shift in the formula that has sin in both side?

Tags: mathematical-physics

Given formula

$asin ( x ) = b sin( x + \phi)$

where $a$ and $b$ are constants. I want to calculate $\phi$.

Comment: Is $x$ a given number, or do you want this to be an identity which holds for all $x$?

Comment: x is a variable. Please see my comment to Dr. Sonnhard

Comment: In that case, you are asking too much! If $a$ and $b$ are given, there will usually not exist such a number $\phi$. Exceptions occur if $a=b$ (in which case $\phi=0$ will do) and if $a=-b$ (then $\phi=\pi$ works).

Answer (score 0):

we obtain for $b\ne 0$
$\frac{a}{b}\sin(x)=\sin(x+\phi)$
$\arcsin\left(\frac{a}{b}\sin(x)\right)-x=\phi$

Comment: thanks very much for the answer. But according to your solution, the value of the phase shift phi will be depent on the value of x? Actually the real formula I have is this: a*sin(2*pi*t)+b*sin(2*pi*t+phi)=c*sin(2*pi*t) These are actually 3 sinwave signals. By adjusting the phase shift in signal 'b', I will be able to match the sum of signal (a+b) to signal c. So, should phi be independent to variable x?